# C# moving the last remaining item in a list box

Tags: c#, listbox, items

This is a Windows Forms Application that connects to a server, gets the tables and converts them to a drop create SQL script. There are two list boxes, lbSource where the initial list of tables is loaded and lbTarget that contains the tables that the user moved there to export.

The problem that occurs is, if I move the last remaining item `(selIndex = 0)`, there is no item left to select `(lbTarget.SetSelected(selIndex, true);)` selIndex gets a value, but the list box is empty (OutOfRange).
I need the code at `(selIndex >= 0)` to select the next item if it's top of the list `(also selIndex = 0)`.

So what I tried to do, was to check if `(listBox.Items.Count == 0)`, but that does not seem to work.

This is the code of what happens if you click the button to move (a) certain item(s) from one list box to the other. Same code for source to target.

```
private void cmdTargetToSource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //move more than one item
    lbTarget.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;

    //sorting the lists
    lbSource.Sorted = true;
    lbTarget.Sorted = true;

    //save the selectedIndex
    int selIndex = lbTarget.SelectedIndex;

    if (lbTarget.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    //moving last entry in listBox sets selIndex higher than lbTarget.Items.Count
    if (selIndex < lbTarget.Items.Count)
    {
        selIndex = selIndex - 1;
    }

    if (selIndex == -1)
    {
        selIndex = selIndex + 1;
    }

    //If there are no items left do nothing
    if (lbTarget.Items.Count == 0)
    {
     return;
    }

    if (selIndex == lbTarget.Items.Count -2)
    {
        selIndex = selIndex - 1;
    }   

    MoveListBoxItems(lbTarget, lbSource);

    //select next item
    if (selIndex >= 0)
    {
        lbTarget.SetSelected(selIndex, true);
    }

    //selectionmode back to single selection
    lbTarget.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
}
```

Comment: Why are you only do `IF` statements? Why can't you use `IF ELSE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let see: when you *click* on `cmdTargetToSource` you want to *move all the selected items* from `ListBox lbSource` to `ListBox lbTarget`, right? 
  In that case, first *extract the method*:

```
private static void MoveSelectedItems(ListBox source, ListBox target) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  else if (null == target)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

  // Indice to move (Linq)
  var indice = source.SelectedIndices.OfType<int>().OrderByDescending(item => item);
  // Place to move (at the end of target listbox, if target is not sorted)
  int place = target.Items.Count;

  // we don't need repaint source as well as target on moving each item
  // which cause blinking, so let's stop updating them for the entire operation
  source.BeginUpdate();
  target.BeginUpdate();
  Boolean sorted = target.Sorted;

  try {
    // switch sorting off so sorting would not change indice 
    // of items inserted
    target.Sorted = false;

    // Move items from source to target
    foreach (var index in indice) {
      target.Items.Insert(place, source.Items[index]);
      target.SelectedIndices.Add(place);

      source.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    }
  }
  finally {
    target.Sorted = true;
    target.EndUpdate();
    source.EndUpdate();
  }
}
```

and then call it

```
  private void cmdTargetToSource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MoveSelectedItems(lbSource, lbTarget);
  }
```

with the *method extracted* you can easily implement a *reverse* move if you want:

```
  private void cmdBackTargetToSource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Just swap source and target:
    MoveSelectedItems(lbTarget, lbSource);
  }
```